# Extra rows being received when matching pairs in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I am attempting to match `customers` who have purchased the same item, ordered by the first customer id `CID`. The query produces correct results but I am getting approximately 37 more rows than I should be receiving.

Upon inspection there appears to be some duplicates in this sense

```
Customer A | Customer B
Customer B | Customer A
```

This only occurs for some matches but not others

```
SELECT DISTINCT ca.name as CUSTOMERA, cb.name as CUSTOMERB
FROM customer ca, customer cb
INNER JOIN YRB_PURCHASE pur1 ON ca.cid = pur1.cid
INNER JOIN YRB_PURCHASE pur2 ON cb.cid = pur2.cid
WHERE pur1.title = pur2.title 
  AND ca.cid > cb.cid;
```

Here is a small example from the database

```
Jon Stewart  | Sydney Crosby
Jake Banning | James Monroe
James Monroe | Jake Banning
```

The last row shouldn't be returned as Jake Banning and James Monroe have already been paired up in row 2

Comment: Please tag the correct DB, post some input data set and what results do you want to see.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Do not mix join syntaxes - stick to @jarlh tip - you are missing a join criteria it seems. How do customer ca, customer cb join besides ca.cid > cb.cid?

Comment: I'm guessing that you have duplicate customer names.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823

Answer (score 0):

If you only want rows where the first name is alphabetically before the second, well just tell SQL that

```
SELECT DISTINCT ca.name as CUSTOMERA, cb.name as CUSTOMERB
FROM customer ca, customer cb
INNER JOIN YRB_PURCHASE pur1 ON ca.cid = pur1.cid
INNER JOIN YRB_PURCHASE pur2 ON cb.cid = pur2.cid
WHERE pur1.title = pur2.title 
  AND ca.name < cb.name;
```

Comment: I require that there are no mirror pairs in the results so that if a pair already appears in one row, the mirror of it shouldn't appear in another.