# How would I create a query that gives me the names of customers with same purchases

Tags: sql, database, db2, relational-database

Which pairs of customers purchased at least one book in common?

List distinct pairs of customers (by name). For each pair of customers, show fist the one with the larger CID; name the two columns customera and customerb.

this is what I have tried but I keep getting an error. And how would I use an alias to rename the column names?

```
select cusA.name, cusB.name
from yrb_customer cusA, yrb_customer cusA, yrb_purchase A, yrb_purchase B
where A.title=B.title
and A.cid<>B.cid;
```

here's what the output is suppose to be:

```
CUSTOMERA            CUSTOMERB
-------------------- --------------------
Jackie Johassen      Al Bore
Margaret Mitchie     Al Bore
Phil Regis           Al Bore
Pretence Parker      Al Bore
Doris Daniels        Andy Aardverk
George Gush          Andy Aardverk
...

282 record(s) selected.


create table yrb_customer (
cid   smallint  not null,
name  varchar(20),
city  varchar(15),
constraint yrb_customer_pk
    primary key (cid));


create table yrb_purchase (
cid    smallint     not null,
club   varchar(15)  not null,
title  varchar(25)  not null,
year   smallint     not null,
when   timestamp    not null,
qnty   smallint     not null,...



insert into yrb_customer (cid, name, city) values
(1,'Tracy Turnip','Richmond'),
(2,'Qfwfq','Pluto'),
(3,'Fuzzy Fowles','Petersburg'),
(4,'Suzy Sedwick','Williamsburg'),...

insert into yrb_purchase (cid,club,title,year,when,qnty) values
(1,'Basic','Will Snoopy find Lucy?',1985,'2001-12-1-11.59.00',1),
(1,'Readers Digest','Flibber Gibber',2000,'2001-12-1-11.59.00',1),
(1,'Readers Digest','Yon-juu Hachi',1948,'1999-4-20-12.12.00',1),
(1,'W&M Club','Nothing but Steak',1991,'2001-12-1-11.59.00',1),
```

Comment: It looks like you need to do an `INNER JOIN' on the cid

Comment: To "rename" columns you can use SELECT col1 as newname1, col2 as whatevername ... FROM tab

Comment: Maybe ask your colleague (or fellow student I suspect!) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029242/extra-rows-being-received-when-matching-pairs-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

The query looks a bit off. For example, the purchases aren't linked to the customer tables. Maybe try:

```
select cusA.name, cusB.name
from yrb_customer cusA, yrb_customer cusB, yrb_purchase A, yrb_purchase B
where cusA.cid=A.cid
and cusB.cid=B.cid
and A.title=B.title
and A.cid > B.cid;
```

You could use JOINs as well to achieve the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below mentioned query

```
Select cusA.name, cusB.name
from yrb_customer cusA, yrb_customer cusB, yrb_purchase A, yrb_purchase B
Where A.cid <> B.cid
and cusA.cid = A.cid
and cusB.cid = B.cid
and A.title = B.title;
```